# How to convert string/numeric columns to categorical columns in python pandas by assigning custom label for the values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stata

When I convert the numerical/string columns in a dataframe to categorical columns, the categories are defined such as in the following code:

```
data = [['Eren Jaeger', 15, 1, 'Soldier' ] , ['Mikasa Ackerman', 14, 1, 'Soldier'], ['Armin Arlert', 14, 1 , 'Soldier'],['Levi Ackerman', 30, 2, 'Captain']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'Rank_num', 'Rank'])
df['Rank'] = df['Rank'].astype('category')
df['Rank'] = df['Rank'].cat.set_categories(["Soldier", "Captain"])
df.to_stata('hello.dta', write_index=False, version = 118)
df['Rank']
```

The output is:

```
0    Soldier
1    Soldier
2    Soldier
3    Captain
Name: Rank, dtype: category
Categories (2, object): ['Soldier', 'Captain']
```

Now if I open the `hello.dta` file in stata, then it shows that in the column `Rank`, `Soldier` is defined as `0` and `Captain` is defined as `1`. But is there any function in pandas that can take pre-defined labels such as if there was a dictionary of value labels:

```
label = {"Rank": {"Soldier": -1, "Captain": 22 ...}  }
```

Then the category data will set the value labels like the labels which is predefined. Then when the dataset is opened in stata, in the `Rank` column, the `Soldier` will show `-1` and `Captain` will show `22` which are the value labels. How can I go this without passing `value_labels` parameter in `to_stata()` function. Is there any function in pandas to do this?

Whatever function I tried, I couldn't find any function  where pre-defined labels could be set in the dataframe categorical columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Rank': ['Soldier', 'Captain'], 'other': [1, 2]})

my_mapping = {"Soldier": -1, "Captain": 22}
df['Rank'] = df['Rank'].map(my_mapping)

df
```

Rank    other
0   -1  1
1   22  2